# SwiftUI : difficulty with dictionary to define a result list of search

Tags: xcode, dictionary, search, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'll try to do one Search View.

I would like to save the result in a dictionary in order to create a list of result but xCode show me this error :

Cannot assign through subscript: 'self' is immutable

My code :

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchListView: View {
    @State var search: String = "test"
    var stringDictionary: Dictionary = [Int: String]()

    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {

                ForEach(chapterData)  { chapter in
                    ForEach(chapter.lines)  { line in
                        HStack {
                            if (self.search == line.text) {
                                HStack {
                                    stringDictionary[0] = line.text
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }

}

struct SearchListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SearchListView(search: "test")
    }
}
```

```
struct Chapter: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id:Int
  let lines: [Line]
}


struct Line: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id: Int
  let text: String 
}
```

Comment: This is so unnecessarily *complex* code. try posting a minimal working code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: You mixed *logic* with *view*. We are using `ForEach` for building the UI, not for filling the dataSource or something.

Comment: I tried to simplify the code. Yes, I understand what you mean. How would you have done to separate the search from the view ?

Comment: I would send the search string to the model and return the result and refresh the UI accordingly.

Comment: OK, I understand. I didn't see this problem from this point of view. Thank's :)